# Create .deb package - can't get dependencies

Tags: linux, installation, dependencies, package, debian

I am trying to create a simple .deb package by following [a wonderful tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html), 
and my problem is that when I try to get the dependencies of the package by executing this command:

```
dpkg-depcheck -d ./configure
```

I get this error:

```
strace: ./configure: command not found
Running strace failed (command line:
strace -e trace=open,execve -f -q -o /tmp/depchqCdeiv ./configure
```

which I don't understand. Do you have any idea about what could be causing this?
This on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that tutorial is not the better approach to create quality deb packages.

Better resources would be:

- [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/)
- [Introducing the Debian packaging tutorial](http://www.lucas-nussbaum.net/blog/?p=640)

About the error, I imagine that the software that you are trying to package doesn't use autotools, and for that reason it doesn't have any `configure` script. The way that the dependencies are checked depends on the build system used. If you don't have a `configure` script, maybe your project root directory has a `SConstructp`, a `setup.py` or simply a `Makefile`.

Giving more information about the software you are trying to package I can provide further help.

Best regards